# Allow certain roles to be run multiple times in an Ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

I made a role whose only job is to download and unpack binary packages from Artifactory. Just about everything I want to install requires me to use this role.

I have a deployment with three major components, and each component will be pulled from Artifactory using this same reusable role. The role takes parameters, for example the name of the package being installed, the Artifactory URL where the binary can be downloaded from.

The reusable role is called from /meta/dependancies.

The problem is that the reusable role only runs once. The second time it's run Ansible skips it (even though the parameters are different).

Is there a way I can tell Ansible that this role must always be run, even if has previously run with different parameters?

Comment: Do you call this role 3 times in a row? Or do you have other roles in between? Anyway my shot is that you have to refactor your roles to avoid running them several times. The whole point of roles is that it is run once on a particular set of machines from inventory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just include the role multiple times in the playbook using different parameter values.

This should do the trick:

```
---

- hosts: server
  tasks:
  - include_role:
       name: artifactory
    vars:
      artifact: 'artifact_1'

  - include_role:
       name: artifactory
    vars:
      artifact: 'artifact_2'
```